# Mapping enums to entities with Groovy

Tags: groovy, enums

I have the following database table:

```
widget_types
------------
widget_type_id
widget_type_name
widget_type_alias
widget_type_description
```

This corresponds to the following Groovy entity class:

```
class WidgetType extends BaseLookupEntity {
    Long id
    String name
    String alias
    String description
}
```

In reality, `WidgetType`/`widget_types` really ought to be `enums`, because they are reference/lookup types with a small number of valid values:

- `RedWidget`
- `SillyWidget`
- `HappyWidget`
- `BerserkingWidget`
- `SausageWidget`

For reasons outside the scope of this question, it is not really possible for me to OR/map the `widget_types` table to an `enum`. And so I have created a "helper enum":

```
enum WidgetTypeLookup {
    Red,
    Silly,
    Happy,
    Berserking,
    Sausage

    static WidgetTypeLookup toWidgetTypeLookup(WidgetType type) {
        // TODO: ???
        null
    }
}
```

The idea here is that the JPA/OR layer will create `WidgetType` instances, but to be able to get real use out of them (type safety, etc.), I'd like to be able to convert them to `WidgetTypeLookups`:

```
// Inside some method...
WidgetType widgetType = getSomehowButStillNotSureWhichTypeItIs()
WidgetTypeLookup wtLookup = WidgetTypeLookup.toWidgetTypeLookup(widgetType)
switch(wtLookup) {
case Happy:
    // etc...
}
```

So I'm struggling to find an efficient "Groovy way" of converting between the POGO type and the enum. Basically implementing the helper method. Any ideas?

Comment: The part that made me thing "oh, oh" is the switch(wtLookup) block. What's an example of something you'd write in such a switch block?

Comment: Emannuel, any type of conditional logic. Perhaps a "happy" widget should go left, but a "berserking" widget should go right. I just find it easier to do this with typesafe enums instead of doing something like: `if(widgetType.alias.equals('HAPPY')) { goLeft() }`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the other answer that there might be better way to address your problem by improving OO design. Although I'll try to fit into your approach.

**First** - couldn't you just do it as follow and map the name as enum straight away?

```
class WidgetType extends BaseLookupEntity {
    Long id
    WidgetName name
    String alias
    String description

    enum WidgetName {
        Red,
        Silly,
        Happy,
        Berserking,
        Sausage
    }
}
```

**Second** - the method you want to implement could be implemented like:

```
static WidgetTypeLookup toWidgetTypeLookup(WidgetType type) {
    values().find {
        it.name() == type.name
    }
}
```

However:

- the condition may need to be adjusted if names don't exactly match
- you may need to handle somehow the case when there is no matching enum found
- the name of the method should be rather something as `fromWidgetType()` then you'll have call like `WidgetTypeLookup.fromWidgetType(widgetType)` instead of redundant `WidgetTypeLookup.toWidgetTypeLookup(widgetType)`

**Third** - Even more groovy would be to implement custom type conversion as follows (I altered original classes names to reflect better what they are IMHO):

```
enum WidgetType {
    Red,
    Silly,
    Happy,
    Berserking,
    Sausage
}

class WidgetTypeDetails {
    Long id
    String name
    String alias
    String description

    Object asType(Class clazz) {
        if (clazz == WidgetType) {
            WidgetType.values().find {
                it.name() == this.name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can go like:

```
WidgetType widgetType = new WidgetTypeDetails(name: 'Red') as WidgetType
```

Answer (score 0):

An enum is a limited number of fixed elements, unless that table have only fixed rows, `Widget Red/Silly/etc` should be subclasses.

You could implement the helper method inside the `WidgetType` class and operate specializations from an inner enum (though they can't reference the outer class)

```
class WidgetType {
    Long id
    String name
    String alias
    String description

    enum Type {
        RED, 
        SAUSAGE {
            def install(container) {
                "installing elongated component into $container"
            }
        }, 
        SILLY, 
        HAPPY, 
        BERSERKING

        def install(container) {
            "installed ${name()} into $container"
        }
    }

    Type getType() {
        Type.values().find { it.name() == name }
    }
}

red = new WidgetType(name: 'RED')

assert red.type.install("main container") == 
        "installed RED into main container"

sausage = new WidgetType(name: 'SAUSAGE')

assert sausage.type.install("display") == 
        "installing elongated component into display"
```

I think `widget.install()` is cooler and more OO (in a sense I don't need to pull the object guts to do something).

Another solution would be if `WidgetType` were an abstract class, and your ORM would instantiate the correct concrete type based on a specific value:

```
abstract class WidgetType {
    Long id
    String name
    String alias
    String description

    abstract install(container)

    enum Type {
        RED(RedWidget), 
        SAUSAGE(SausageWidget), 
    }

    static WidgetType from(type, properties) {
        Type.values().find { it.name() == type }
            .clazz
            .newInstance(properties: properties)
    }
}

class RedWidget extends WidgetType {
    def install(container) { 'red installing into $container' }
}

class SausageWidget extends WidgetType {
    def install(container) { 'elongated component installing into $container' }
}
```

The fake ORM:

```
class ORM {
    def container = [
        (1) : [
            id: 1, 
            name: 'RED', 
            alias: 'my red alias',
            description: 'this art red' ],
        (2) : [
            id: 2, 
            name: 'SAUSAGE', 
            alias: 'long component', 
            description: 'sausage component' ] 
    ]

    def get(id) {
        container[it].with {
            WidgetType.from(it.name, id)
        }
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
red = new ORM().get(1)
assert red.install('main') == 
        'red installing into main'

sausage = new ORM().get(2)
assert sausage.install('display') == 
        'elongated component installing into display'
```